# How to Load ASCII Character into Snowflake using COPY Command

Tags: csv, copy, ascii, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My CSV file contains the value "a'test," but when I load it into Snowflake using the copy command with the Custom file format, I get "a?test" loaded Is there a way to deal with it?
Thanks

Here is my file format

```sql
CREATE FILE FORMAT TEST2 
    COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
    FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' 
    SKIP_HEADER = 0 
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' 
    TRIM_SPACE = FALSE 
    ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE 
    ESCAPE = 'NONE' 
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' 
    DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
    NULL_IF = ('NULL', 'null', '');
```

Comment: Please share your file format. Are you sure that it is actually a ' character and not a 'dodgy' character that is just being displayed as a ' ?

Comment: @NickW Here is my file format ---CREATE FILE FORMAT TEST2 COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' SKIP_HEADER = 0 FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\134' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ('NULL', 'null', '');
Let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Can you share a sample file containing this character?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I am not able to see any option how can I attach the file. For sample you can use the values and add into csv file. 

LastName SSN   ContactAddress
O'test         N/A    test
test1        123        test2

Comment: Also I am able to load the value using insert statement and JSON file but not with the CSV.

Comment: Can you upload and share the original file on s3, google drive, github, or anywhere that can host a file?